# Is there any holomorphic function in a unit ball such that $f(1/n)=\frac{1}{n \ln{n}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms

Is there any holomorphic function in a unit ball such that $f(1/n)=\frac{1}{n \ln{n}}$ for $n=2,3,\dots$

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Only thing I know is that $f(0)=0$ if such function exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f(1/n)=1/(n\log n)$. Then $f(0)=0$, by continuity of $f$, and thus $f(z)=zg(z)$, where $g$ is also holomorphic in the unit disc. Now
$$
g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{\log n}.
$$
But this means that $g(0)=0$, due to continuity of $g$ at $z=0$, and thus $g(z)=zh(z)$, where $h$ is holomorphic in the unit ball. Now we have that
$$
g\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{\log n},
$$
and hence
$$
h\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{\log n}\to\infty,
$$
as $n\to \infty$, while $h(1/n)\to h(0)\in\mathbb C$. Contradiction. Thus no such $f$ exists!

Comment: you used here identity theorem? can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I did not use the Identity Theorem. I simply found an example.

Comment: But how $f(z)=z^2$ satisfies the condition that is required?

Comment: See my updated answer. I had not understood correctly the question.

Comment: How do we explain that there is $g$ holomorphic such that $f(z)=zg(z)$?

Comment: ahh i get it now. we assume that $f(z)$ is holomorphic and we know that $z$ is holomorphic so their quotient is holomorphic outside of 0 yes? Maybe you can explain it better to me, please?